# To show alertbox during time interval

Tags: android

I want to show  alertbox during time interval set by the user and to show alertbox for 1 minute .If no action is performed within 1 minute then sent message and make call to a particular number.So please help to tackle my problem.anyone can help me.....

Answer (score 2):

```
Timer myTimer;
myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerMethod();
                }

            }, 0, 10000); 
        }

    }
    private void TimerMethod()
    {
        //This method is called directly by the timer
        //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

        //We call the method that will work with the UI
        //through the runOnUiThread method.
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               

        //Do something to the UI thread here


        }
    };
```

Try this out.
Let me know if this works.